# it is deleting the game object instead of deleting its clone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. The results I want is clone the game object set it active then delete game Object clone. But instead, It's it deleting the game Object base which is stopping from happening again.

```
if (AttackChoice == 2)
{
    MaxedOut();
    gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
     var clone = Instantiate(Pt, portalSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
    _clones.Add(clone);
    clone.transform.parent = null;
    Pt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    
    Destroy(clone);
    gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = originalColor;
}
```

Comment: my b i thought i did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> The results I want is clone the game object set it active then delete game Object clone

and you clone the GameObject `Pt`:

```
var clone = Instantiate(Pt, portalSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

but then you don't set it active, you set `Pt` active instead:

```
Pt.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

and then later you destroy the clone:

```
Destroy(clone);
```

Your question is poorly worded so I can't tell what exactly the issue is here. It sounds like you think you're deleting `Pt`, the source for the clone instantiation, which is preventing you from re-running the instantiation code (because it's null), but you are NOT destroying `Pt` in the snippet you've provided.

You **are** adding the `clone` to a `_clones` list, which makes me think you're doing something else, and I'm wondering if the scripts that are living on the `Pt` GameObject are somehow triggering the object to self-destruct. In that case, just active the correct object by:

```
clone.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

instead of activating the `Pt` object.